# Wrong values being picked up by range.value

Tags: vba, excel

The below code should take the values from certain cells and use them as parameters in a `RANGE` so I can copy and paste the correct contents from one sheet to another.

I do not have any compile errors, but the wrong values are being taken, meaning the output that is copied is wrong.

For example, the starting row of values is 6 (Located in AB4), for some reason it is copying from row 2, not 6.
The amount of rows to copy is 3 (Located in AJ4 [as 4 hence the -1]), but is copying 5 rows, not 3.

I am 100% certain AB4 and AJ4 on the sheet named Weights contain the values mentioned.

```
Sub CopyDataToRefined()

Dim AmtRows As Integer
Dim ColLet As String
Dim RowStart As Integer
Dim RowEnd As Integer
Dim Rng1 As Range

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(Module2.FirstBBSName)

AmtRows = Sheets("Weights").Range("AJ4").Value
ColLet = Sheets("Weights").Range("AF5").Value
RowStart = Sheets("Weights").Range("AB4").Value
RowEnd = Sheets("Weights").Range("AJ4").Value - 1

Set Rng1 = ws.Range(ColLet & RowStart & ":" & ColLet & RowEnd)

Rng1.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("RefindData").Range("H3")

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the output of `Debug.Print Rng1.Address` after you set it? • And always use `Long` instead of `Integer` unless communicating with old APIs. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.

Comment: `H2:H6` which simply isn't right. Noted I have changed them to `Long`

Comment: `Debug.Print RowStart` Show 6, which is correct

Comment: This sounds very strange, can you add all the values of `debug.print` for `AmtRows`, `ColLet`, `RowStart`, `RowEnd` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. It should be:

```
AmtRows = Sheets("Weights").Range(AmtRowsValue).Value
ColLet = Sheets("Weights").Range(ColLetValue).Value
RowStart = Sheets("Weights").Range(RowStartValue).Value
RowEnd = Sheets("Weights").Range(AmtRowsValue).Value + Sheets("Weights").Range(RowStartValue).Value - 1
```

In the original `RowEnd` would equal 2, which screwed everything up.

What i really needed was to take the amount of rows, add the starting row value, minus 1. This gives me the proper value for the `RowEnd` which equals 8 in this instance (3 total rows of data starting from and including row 6)

Thanks to Peh for the light bulb moment.